# how to avoid overriding drawRect when clipping

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, drawrect, clip

At the moment i'm overriding `drawRect` in a view in order to be able to clip a colored rectangle with a mask (using `CGContextClipToMask`inside `drawRect`).
Sometimes I change the color of this clipped rectangle. In this case `drawRect` gets called again, redrawing and clipping the rectangle with the new color.
Now I don't want to change the color at once, but animate this. The problem is, that animations are not performed when overriding drawRect (drawRect only gets called one time and immediately).

Is there a way to perform this animation, maybe by subclassing the view, so that I still override `drawRect`in the superclass, but the animation is somehow performed through the subclass so that drawRect from the superclass gets performed multiple times during the animation?

Or is also possible not to override `drawRect` at all, and still be able to clip this rectangle with the mask somehow?
`drawRect`looks something like this:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGImageRef maskImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:maskName] CGImage];
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, rect, maskImage);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.currentColor);
CGContextFillRect( ctx, rect );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use a CALayer to mask your view (don't forget to import QuartzCore):

```
maskLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:maskName].CGImage; // maskLayer is a CALayer
view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Now assuming you have a method `-(void)animate` in your view controller, you have execute it multiple times using a timer, or using recursive calls to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`.

Comment: Awesome, with your approach I didn't have to override drawRect so I can finally use animations. I didn't have to use a timer or recursively execute an animation method, because I can use standard CoreAnimation now. Thanks a lot! One thing to note is, that you have to use png images or some images with clear color (black and white masks don't work anymore, but thats no problem). Also you have to set the layer frame to the bounds of the view you want to mask using     maskLayer.frame = [self bounds];

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a timer that fires to redraw repeatedly over time whenever the color is changed. When the user picks a new color, star an `NSTimer` that fires, say 10x a second. When the timer fires, update the current color to be partway from the start to the end color, and invalidate the view. After you reach the final color, kill the timer.

Comment: thanks, it sounds like it should work, but also sounds somehow like  reinventing the (animation) wheel. If theres no other option I'll use this.